# shiny click on plot update input

Tags: r, shiny

I have this very simple shiny app

When input changes, the graph changes accordingly

When a point is selected within the graph the corresponding model is displayed on the right of the input text box

I would like to see the selection to be displayed inside the text box

Can anyone please point me in the right direction

Thanks for any help

```
  require(ggplot2)
  require(dplyr)
  require(Cairo)   
  require(dplyr)
  
    
  mtcars2 <- datasets::mtcars %>% rownames_to_column(var = 'model') 
  
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    
      fluidRow(
        column(width = 3,
               selectInput(inputId = '.model', label = 'input model', choices = mtcars2$model,  selected = NULL)),
        br(),br(),
        column(width = 3,
               textOutput('click_1A'), label = 'selected model')
            ),
      fluidRow(
        column(width = 8,
             plotOutput("plot1", height = 350, brush = "plot_brush", click = "plot_click")),
      )
    )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    
    
    
    global <- reactiveValues(.model = NULL) 
   
    
    # scatter plot
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      selected_model <- input$.model
      ggplot(mtcars2, aes(x=mpg,y=disp), color = 'red') + 
        geom_point(size = 3, col = 'red') + 
        geom_point(data = filter(mtcars2, model == selected_model), col = 'blue', size = 5) + 
        theme_bw() +
        theme(legend.position = 'none') 
      
      
    })
    
    
    # MODEL name 
     output$click_1A <- renderText({
       
       near_out <- nearPoints(mtcars2, input$plot_click, addDist = TRUE)
       global$.model <- near_out %>% 
         pull(model) 
     })     
         
    }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: maybe add something like `maxpoints = 1, threshold = Inf` to `nearPoints`?

Comment: @Andrea To clarify, did you want your `selectInput` to change when a point is clicked on? If you click on the Valiant point did you want your `selectInput` to change to Valiant (using something like `updateSelectInput`)?

Comment: @Ben ... That exactly what I trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ben

Here is the clean version of what was trying to achieve:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(tidyr)
require(tibble)
require(lubridate)
require(Cairo)
require(dplyr)
  
    
mtcars2 <- datasets::mtcars %>% rownames_to_column(var = 'model') 
  
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    
      fluidRow(
        column(width = 3,
               selectInput(inputId = '.model', label = 'input model', choices = mtcars2$model,  selected = NULL)),
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(width = 8,
             plotOutput("plot1", height = 350, brush = "plot_brush", click = "plot_click")),
      )
    )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    
    global <- reactiveValues(.model = NULL) 
   
    
    # scatter plot
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      selected_model <- input$.model
      ggplot(mtcars2, aes(x=mpg,y=disp, label = model), color = 'red') + 
        geom_point(size = 3, col = 'red') + 
        geom_point(data = filter(mtcars2, model == selected_model), col = 'blue', size = 5) + 
        #geom_text() + 
        theme_bw() +
        theme(legend.position = 'none') 
      
      
    })
    
      observeEvent(
        eventExpr = input$plot_click, 
        handlerExpr = {
          selected_model <- nearPoints(mtcars2, input$plot_click, maxpoints = 1, addDist = F) %>% pull(model)
          updateSelectInput(session, inputId = ".model", choices = mtcars2$model, selected = selected_model)}
        ) 
    }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```